# I can not get a response from the controller in ajax

Tags: laravel-8

I have made a function of changing the Avatar. This works, but when I try to return a response in ajax, json content is displayed in my browser and do not get anything in ajax

My ajax

```
$('changeBlogLogoForm').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                method: $(form).attr('method'),
                data: new FormData(form),
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);
                }
                //     toastr.remove();
                //     console.log('+');
                //     if (data.status === 1) {
                //         toastr.success(data.msg);
                //         $(form)[0].reset();
                //     } else {
                //         toastr.error(data.msg);
                //     }
                // }
            });
```

My function in controller

```
public function changeBlogLogo(Request $request)
    {
        $settings = Setting::find(1);
        $logo_path = 'back/dist/img/logo-favicon';
        $old_logo = $settings->getAttributes()['blog_logo'];
        $file = $request->file('blog_logo');
        $filename = time() . '_' . rand(1, 100000) . '_sdblog_logo_png';

        if ($request->hasFile('blog_logo')) {

            if ($old_logo != null && File::exists(public_path($logo_path . $old_logo))) {
                File::delete(public_path($logo_path . $old_logo));
            }
            $upload = $file->move(public_path($logo_path), $filename);

            if ($upload) {
                $settings->update([
                    'blog_logo' => $filename
                ]);
                return response()->json(['status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Success']);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Error']);
            }
        } else {
            dd('No file');
        }
    }
```

I tried to display the **data** in the console, but nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
let value = e.target.files[0]

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('blog_logo', value)
```

and don't forget to add multipart form data in your jquery ajax

```
contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
```

hope this work

Comment: No, it didn't work. The idea is that everything works, and the image changes, only that the JSON response I get on an empty page in the browser